# Take right string after ^

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, select

I have two records of this data: I want this in MS SQL

```
03/28/2018^10/22/2018 
02/29/2018^10/28/2018^12/06/2019
```

I want to get right string data after ^. My output should be...

```
10/22/2018 
12/06/2019
```

If i have data

```
test1^test2^test3^test4  
test5  
test6^test7  
null
```

output should be

test4
   test5
   test7
   null

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach may be to just take the 10 rightmost characters:

```
SELECT RIGHT(mycol, 10)
FROM   mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `right()` and `charindex()`:

```
select right(str, charindex('^', str + '^') - 1)
from (values ('02/29/2018^10/28/2018^12/06/2019')) v(str)
```

Comment: Its throwing an error: Msg 536, Level 16, State 2, Line 23
Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.

Comment: I think you need `length(str) - charindex('^',str)` for the right function since it is the number of character from the right not the index starting at the left

Comment: @Dinesh. . .  So, you don't have a `^` in some string value.

Comment: 'length' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @Dinesh -- right on sql server it is len() -- on db2 it is length

Comment: yes you are right yogesh. How to handle if there is no ^ in same field?

Comment: @Dinesh. . .  Re-copy the code & try i have edited the code recently.

Comment: If I have a data some thing like this....test1^test2^test3^. I want output=test3. In some rows i have only test1 and other rows having nulls. It should handled.

Comment: @Dinesh . . . That is not the question that you asked.  This question seems to explicitly want the string after the *last* `^`.  If you have another question, ask it as a *new* question.

Answer (score 0):

If the `dates` are limited in three parts (`date1^date2^date3^date3`) then you can use [PARSENAME()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) :

```
SELECT t.col, PARSENAME(REPLACE(t.col, '^', '.'), 1)
FROM table t;
```

Comment: did you test this with the examples the op gave -- eg having a `/` -- this is not legal in object names so I would assume parsename would fail.